# utime and stime returned values are still 0 after some time running the process?

Tags: linux, time, proc, stat

I am reading information from the file /proc/[PID]/stat and I would like to parse the fields `utime` and `stime` of the current process running main, but those values are equal to 0?

Here is a minimal C test to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char *pathname = (char *) malloc(30*sizeof(char));
  pid_t pid = getpid();
  int utime, stime, cutime, cstime, result;
  int total = 0;
  int i = 0;
  if (pathname == NULL) return -1;

  sprintf(pathname, "/proc/%d/stat", pid);
  fp = fopen(pathname, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) return -1;

  // Busy loop to cause time to be spent
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
      total = total + i;
    }

  printf("total value has been calculated %d \n", total);  
  result = fscanf (fp, "%*d %*s %*c %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %d %d %d %d\n",
  &utime,
  &stime,
  &cutime,
  &cstime);
  if (result < 4)
    {
      return -1;
    }
  else
    {
      printf("utime = %d \nstime = %d \ncutime = %d \ncstime = %d \n", utime, stime, cutime, cstime);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
total value has been calculated 499500 
utime = 0 
stime = 0 
cutime = 0 
cstime = 0
```

I have also tried to cat the `/proc/[PID]/stat` of my program and I have found that these values remain 0 even if the program is sleeping (sleep(200))

Is there something I am missing here?
Thanks

Comment: `utime` and `ctime` report CPU time. If the process is sleeping, it doesn't use any CPU time.

Comment: how about doing a loop that calculates some value like the one in the example, it also returns 0 then ?

Comment: If you compiled with optimizations, it might be removing the loop and simply doing `total = 1000;`.

Comment: @Barmar yep you were right, actually even disabling the gcc optimization does not have any impact there need to be a high load, so I have just added this code (of threads being in a busy loop in the code)and I have got the results see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting